# How harmful is writing to a file, once every second, on flash memory?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, flash-memory

Good afternoon,

We are developing an app for smartwatch and mobile phone.

We need to transfer some data from the phone to the smartwatch and want to avoid using proprietary libraries.

So we implemented a webserver in our app from which the smartwatch is able to read data.

The problem is that in order to accomplish this, we need to write some data to a file every second.

The smartwatch is downloading that data to a file every second. This means every second there are some bytes written on flash memory.

We are wondering how harmful for the memory of our devices this is. We'd rather avoid rewriting the server to use RAM only.

So we are wondering, since the OS'es are keeping logs themselves on memory, if it is bad practice to write to a file every second.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: most OS running on flash memory have built-in mechanisms for avoiding exactly that. Typically, things are kept in cache and flushed to the disk periodically.

Comment: alternatively, you could consider a different architecture, based on push rather than poll.

Comment: also, I don't understand what you mean by `we (...) want to avoid using proprietary libraries`. what libraries?

Comment: Sorry to put too little information in my piece, but we are developing for Samsung Gear S at this point. But our app is a crossplatform cordova application. Samsung forces us to use the Tizen SDK which forces us to make apps in html/css/js. We are forced to use the Tizen SDK for data transfer with an TouchWhizz device. We are preparing to make it a bit more general and open up a localhost API for the watch to access. When we are going to start development for iWatch or motorola or anything else, we just need to read the REST API data, not implement every library for every supplier there is.

Comment: Will be harmful for the battery.

Comment: And why will that be harmful? Will it destroy the battery? Because the app will run with a powercable connected to the device. But could you explain a little bit more in detail? because njzk2 says it's handled by cache. I don't see why that would be more power intensive other than the additional logic that has to run.